# SQL Select where values IN List string

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, where-clause

I select data with this query

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_post` WHERE cate IN (15)
```

But only records can be found that The number 15 is the first like : "15,16,18" , "15"
can not be found If the number is 15 in the middle or last like : "14,15,16"

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: You're having this problem because your database is poorly designed. You'll probably have more problems in the future because of this design mistake of storing multiple values in a column.

Comment: Never ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a [specific string function called `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for the purpose of searching for a value in a comma-separated string:

```
select * from tbl_post where find_in_set('15', cat) > 0
```

While this will work for your specific use-case, let me pinpoint that storing delimited list in relational databases is *not a good practice*, and should be generally avoided. You should have a separate table to store `cate`s, which each value on a separate row.

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Answer (score 0):

Simply using "like" might help -

```
select * from tbl_post where cate like '15,%' or cate like '%,15,%' or cate 
like '%15';
```

cate like '15,%' : Will get the 15 placed at the beginning

cate like '%,15,%' : Will get the 15 placed in the middle

cate like '%15' : Will get the 15 placed at the end